# Pattern name, storing values as static variables in a function

Tags: c++, static

Just to confirm to myself that it worked, I wrote the following code (yes it is very ugly):

```
#include <iostream>

int* static_int(int i)
{
    static int j;
    j = i;
    return &j;
}

int main ()
{
    int* s_int = static_int(5);
    static_int(6);
    std::cout << *s_int << std::endl;
}
```

The code works as intended and prints `6`.

At the moment, I can't think of a use-case where there isn't a better way of doing something like this, but I was wondering, whether it is reccommended or not, does this programming pattern have a defined name?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it had. Unless you can describe what recurring problem it solves, why that is a real problem, and how your "pattern" solves that problem, I don't think it even qualifies as a "pattern".

Comment: @molbdnilo should I be calling it something other than a pattern then? I'd have thought that it needn't be useful or good to qualify (though you could probably call such things an _antipattern_?)

Comment: This is known as the Remember-the-last-value-passed-and-return-a-pointer-to-it Idiom.

Comment: @Baldrickk It's just a bit of code, and a pretty pointless one at that. Most code is "just a bit of code", not a pattern. Unless you see that kind of thing cropping up regularly, it's not an "antipattern" either. For something to be a pattern, it must be recurring with some regularity; the GoF book that coined the term contains recurring solutions to problems that had been solved many times - they weren't invented out of thin air and labelled "patterns".

Comment: @molbdnilo in this case of course it is just a bit of code, that is in keeping with providing a MCVE.  It could very well be a _style_ that is used many times 'in the wild' (and I have seen similar before). In which case, if it is solving a recurring problem (well or not) it'd likely be considered a pattern of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++, this is not an extremely common pattern to use. Usually data would be stored within objects, rather than as a static of a function. However, static variables declared in functions like this are guaranteed (including thread safety) to only be created once. This can be useful for many things. For example, if you think about it, the code you created creates an integer singleton: that is this function creates and returns a reference to an integer, always the same integer. This is true no matter how many times or in how many threads the function is called. Only one copy of integer j will ever exist. You can read more about the singleton pattern, just Google it, it's very well known. Another use is to make sure some function only gets called once using a guard variable:

```
void output_guard(){
  bool guard = func_call_once();
}
```

This ensures that the function func_call_once only gets called once, which can often be useful.